Advantages, Disadvantages, and Specific Use Cases of Duplex Construction and Tweakable AEAD
I understand the operational mechanisms of Duplex construction and tweakable Authenticated Encryption as used in AEAD schemes. I am interested in a comparative analysis of these cryptographic techniques.

The main advantages and disadvantages of Duplex construction and tweakable AEAD?
Specific use cases where each method is particularly effective?


Do you mean tweakable block cipher based AEADs? As far as I know, there's been much less adoption of tweakable block ciphers in general compared to other types of algorithm. By contrast, the sponge/duplex constructions have been very successful. A big part of this is probably the simplicity/ease of implementation and the amount of analysis. The main downside is the lack of parallelism. There are ways around that, but it adds complexity.

Yes , tweakable block cipher based AEAD.
